# Can anyone spot the SQL mistake in this MS Access SQL code I wrote?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

Here are the tables: [Tables & Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzo12.png)

My objective is to state the Service Rep First Name, Service Rep Last Name and the hours remaining which is calculated by deducting [Service Requests].[Total Hours] - [Service Requests].[Hours Spent].

```
  SELECT
[Service Rep].[First Name],
[Service Rep].[Last Name],
[Service Requests].[Total Hours] - [Service Requests].[Hours Spent] AS [Hours Remaining]
FROM [Service Rep]  INNER JOIN Client ON
[Service Rep].[Service Rep Number] = Client.[Service Rep Number] 
INNER JOIN  [Service Requests] ON 
Client.[Client Number] = [Service Requests].[Client Number] 
INNER JOIN [Service Requests] ON
[Service Requests].[Service Code] = [Service].[Service Code] 
group by [Service Rep].[First Name],
[Service Rep].[Last Name];
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTXmV.png)
I'm receiving this - in query expression . (Error 3075)

can anyone tell me what is wrong in my SQL Query?

***Correct code thanks to the help of Gordon Linoff:***

```
SELECT [Service Rep].[First Name], [Service Rep].[Last Name],
       SUM([Service Requests].[Total Hours] - [Service Requests].[Hours Spent]) AS [Hours Remaining]
FROM (([Service Rep]  INNER JOIN
       Client
       ON [Service Rep].[Service Rep Number] = Client.[Service Rep Number]
      ) INNER JOIN
      [Service Requests]
      ON Client.[Client Number] = [Service Requests].[Client Number] 
     ) INNER JOIN
     [Service]
     ON [Service Requests].[Service Code] = [Service].[Service Code] 
GROUP BY [Service Rep].[First Name], [Service Rep].[Last Name]
ORDER BY SUM([Service Requests].[Total Hours] - [Service Requests].[Hours Spent]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems.  Not know what you are doing, there are three obvious ones:

- MS Access requires ungainly parentheses for multiple `JOIN`s.
- Your `SELECT` columns are inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.
- `GROUP BY` is referencing a table alias that is not defined.

Perhaps you want:

```
SELECT [Service Rep].[First Name], [Service Rep].[Last Name],
       SUM([Service Requests].[Total Hours] - [Service Requests].[Hours Spent]) AS [Hours Remaining]
FROM (([Service Rep]  INNER JOIN
       Client
       ON [Service Rep].[Service Rep Number] = Client.[Service Rep Number]
      ) INNER JOIN
      [Service Requests]
      ON Client.[Client Number] = [Service Requests].[Client Number] 
     ) INNER JOIN
     [Service Requests]
     ON [Service Requests].[Service Code] = [Service].[Service Code] 
GROUP BY [Service Rep].[First Name], [Service Rep].[Last Name];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Gordon, I'm new to SQL on MS Access, it's great to learn about the parentheses for multiple joins. In your code you missed the aggregate function in the ORDER BY statement and the GROUP BY statement uses an undefined ALIAS which I corrected.